# Mongo connections never released - Django and Mongoengine running on gunicorn with gevent

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I have a django application using mongoengine running on gunicorn with gevent workers. Under load, mongo connection count climbs up to about 3 thousand and never goes back down. Even after the load test is completed, the number of mongo connections stays constant. A restart of gunicorn releases the connections.

Package Versions

```
gunicorn==0.17.4
mongoengine==0.8.7
pymongo==2.7
```

mongodb 2.6.0

I have my mongoengine connection settings in an environment specific django settings file:

```
MONGO_DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'DB': '****',
        'HOST': ***********:27017',
        'PORT': 27017
    }
}

from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
from mongoengine import connect
connect(MONGO_DATABASES['default']['DB'], host=MONGO_DATABASES['default']['HOST'],       port=MONGO_DATABASES['default']['PORT'], max_pool_size=100)
```

Is there something I need to do to make sure that unused connections eventually get released?

Thanks,

Doug

Comment: Hi Douglas Hall, did you where experimenting something like this issue: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127658/sudden-mongodb-high-connections-queues-db-stops-responding

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are looking for is a configuration option called `maxIdleTimeMS`, which is meant to be used for cleaning up after load spikes (among other things).

According to the docs:

> maxIdleTimeMS - maximum time in millis a socket can sit idle in the
>   pool before being closed and discarded. Useful for cleaning up after a
>   load spike.

Sadly, this option is currently (March 2015) *not available in the pymongo driver* (which mongoengine uses under the hood), but it's being worked on! [See the relevant JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-658) (and don't forget to upvote the issue!). It should be available with pymongo 3.1 in a few months.